# ipaddress is not working in xampp

Tags: xampp

I installed XAMPP in windows 2003 server. I am checking the XAMPP status by using localhost it is working.

If I give ipaddres in the same machine where the xampp is installed then it is not connecting.

I made the changes in apache/httpd.conf file Listen to ipaddress:80 but still it is not working.

what would be the problem. Is the problem with the XAMPP or windows server.

Comment: Did you restart XAMPP after you changed its config file?

Comment: yes i done it many times and tested it but no effect.